# Can detect magic find a detect thoughts spell in effect?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic

One NPC casts a *detect thoughts* spell before meeting with the PC. Once with the PC, he starts using *detect thoughts* to read the minds of the PC around him.

One of the PCs happens to have a *detect magic* spell active and is concentrating on the area.

What will the *detect magic* spell reveal?  Will the NPC show a magical aura due to the functioning *detect thoughts* spell?

Comment: Just so I can determine what the question's asking, is there something about the spell *detect thoughts* in particular that leads to the belief that a *detect magic* spell would or could *not* pick up the spell's aura? Or is there something else going on here, like the idea that *detect thoughts* is an area (emanation) spell or something?

Comment: I believe casting detect thought that allows you to read other people's mind is kind of enchanting yourself with a spell, so you would radiate a magical aura for the duration of the spell if detect magic is used, whether you use the spell to read minds, or not.  But this has raised some arguments I would like to have your opinion

Comment: O, okay. So the question's more along the lines of *Does an ongoing magic effect possess a magic aura even if the caster isn't currently actively using that ongoing magic effect?* or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, it can.

[Detect thoughts](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectThoughts.htm) is a spell with a school and duration like any other.  I see no textual reference why it would not be detectable by [detect magic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/detectMagic.htm), which should reveal presence of a magic aura, then number, then strength, location and school (Divination, on a spellcraft check) as normal.

Note, when the caster casts the spell is what's important.  The caster would be concentrating the entire time on maintaining the spell, regardless if they are probing thoughts.  I think the word "use" here may be the cause of your confusion.  Consider: "Presence or absence of magic".